Is clearing caches the correct solution for the "No application encryption key has been specified" error after running php artisan optimize?
I was facing the following error in my Laravel app after running the php artisan optimize command on my EC2 Ubuntu server:
[2024-11-25 10:31:53] production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Encryption\\MissingAppKeyException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified.

What I tried:
I followed these steps to fix the issue:
Ran the following commands:
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear

After running these commands, the issue was resolved, and the app started working again.
My Question:
While this fixed the issue, I am wondering if clearing these caches is the correct or recommended solution for this kind of error. Specifically:
Is this a common or acceptable fix for the "No application encryption key has been specified" error after running php artisan optimize?
Are there any underlying issues that might have caused this behavior, or is this a standard procedure to resolve the issue?
I’d appreciate any insights on whether clearing the caches is the right approach or if I should consider other steps to prevent this issue from happening again.

This question is similar to: No Application Encryption Key Has Been Specified. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The question is different. The problem I mentioned occures after running php artisan optimize

I don't think it is. php artisan optimize should only clear the config cache and cache the routes again, which indicates your problem stems from something else. I'm assuming you ran php artisan key:generate when you released your application and that you did'nt remove your .env file in some other way?

php artisan optimize is essentially a wrapper around the config:cache, route:cache, and view:clear commands. My problem is related to php artisan config:cache. env('APP_KEY') and config('app.key') always return null from tinker but the app key exists in the .env file

php artisan config:cache solved the issue for me
